# VFP 9 SP2 with MSSCCI: slow project loading

Tags: tfs, visual-foxpro, msscci

Is it possible, that MSSCCI make VFP project loading slow? Project has 1000+ files, workspace is server. Project loads about 120+ seconds. Network traffic is greater during loading, CPU and memory no significant change. How can I optimalize loading project please?

SOLUTION:

NO, it seems that slow loading is consequence of using MSSCCI provider for  little large projects source controlled in VFP.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Which version of MSSCCI are you using? Do you mean you load project on local slowly, or get project from TFS  slowly? Are specific people experiencing or are all people experiencing it? How do you deploy TFS, single server or two tier? Do you install anti-virus software?

Comment: We using MSSCCI (2013&2015 MSSCCI Provider 32-bit) for connect to Visual Studio Team Services. We try it on two computers - Windows 10 (no antivirus), Windows 7 (antivirus installed) and both same problem. Loading is slow when project is source-controlled (online), when disconnect network (work offline), project loads quickly.

Comment: Do you have proxy enabled in your network environment?

Comment: No, we don't. Can be problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We looked into moving from Visual SourceSafe to TFS a few years ago. When the VFP project was integrated with TFS, opening the project took longer than with VSS.  There were also other oddities with the integration, such as not being able to see when a file was already checked out by someone else.  We ended up abandoning the idea and stuck with VSS.  That said, I wouldn't necessarily blame the MSSCCI provider. It probably has more to do with the way VFP queries source control data.

Note that you are not required to use the VFP project integration.  You can use a separate source control client to check files in/out.  You'll need a process for generating text versions of binary files (SCX, VCX, etc.).

FWIW, opening projects with VSS can also be slow. Upgrading our VSS server made a big difference.  You may find the same if you are running TFS on an older/slower server.

Comment: Finally we will use Mercurial over Bitbucket and SourceTree Client. So using external source control. Thank you for you suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using it so I cannot directly comment on it.

A project is merely a table, and a project with 1000+ files would be roughly mean around 2Mb which is nothing for today's networking (even if it meant to bring down all that data). Normally it should open instantly or with 1-2 seconds delay at most (assuming you are not using an extremely slow network).

Comment: Yes, you right. Hovewer I think MSSCCI during project loading connect VSTS for get some metainformations about all source controlled files and this make loading slow down. But I think it should be quick.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please provide more details about your environment.
2. Make sure your TFS and MSSCCI are used latest version.
3. Try on another client machine to see whether your issue would be reproduced.
4. Create a new workspace to see whether the performance persists.

Comment: Windows 10 and Windows 7, With and without antivirus, MSSCCI 2013&2015 32 bit, VSTS. Project 1000+ files. All last updated. And Visual Fox Pro 8 and 9 SP2.
I try new workspace, no change.
Thanks